# Are those alternatives exactly equal to what they replace: "very + adjective"?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary, synonyms, intensifiers

Thanks to this cool [webpage](https://7esl.com/words-to-use-instead-of-very/), I got the following rich adjective vocabulary list:

```
 Furious —> Very angry 
 Gorgeous —> Very beautiful 
 Massive —> Very big 
 Dull —> Very boring 
 Deafening —> Very noisy 
 Destitute —> Very poor 
 Stingy —> Very cheap 
 Spotless —> Very clean 
 Brief —> Very short 
 Arduous —> Very difficult 
 Arid —> Very dry 
 Rapid —> Very quick 
 Awful —> Very bad 
 Intelligent —> Very smart 
 Sorrowful —> Very sad 
 Distraught —> Very upset 
 Freezing —> Very cold 
 Forceful —> Very strong 
 Colossal —> Very huge 
 Serene —> Very calm 
 Hideous —> Very ugly 
 Petite —> Very small 
 Hilarious —> Very funny 
 Hushed —> Very quiet 
 Wealthy —> Very rich 
 Costly —> Very expensive 
 Filthy —> Very dirty 
 Towering —> Very tall 
 Effortless —> Very easy 
 Soaked —> Very wet 
 Sluggish —> Very slow 
 Excellent —> Very good 
 Idiotic —> Very stupid 
 Ecstatic —> Very happy 
 Exhilarating —> Very exciting 
 Hot —> Very warm 
 Frail —> Very weak 
 Tiny —> Very little 
 Luminous —> Very bright 
 Swamped —> Very busy 
 Cautious —> Very careful 
 Obvious —> Very clear 
 Vibrant —> Very colorful 
 Perplexed —> Very confused 
 Innovative —> Very creative 
 Bustling —> Very crowded 
 Cherished —> Very dear 
 Profound —> Very deep 
 Desolate —> Very empty 
 Thrilled —> Very excited 
 Lavish —> Very fancy 
 Obese —> Very fat 
 Amiable —> Very friendly 
 Overjoyed —> Very glad 
 Terrific —> Very great 
 Leaden —> Very heavy 
 Starving —> Very hungry 
 Battered —> Very hurt 
 Huge —> Very large 
 Indolent —> Very lazy 
 Extensive —> Very long 
 Slack —> Very loose 
 Exact —> Very accurate 
 Fearful —> Very afraid 
 Intelligent —> Very clever 
 Adorable —> Very cute 
 Tedious —> Very dull 
 Keen —> Very eager 
 Wicked —> Very evil 
 Quick —> Very fast 
 Ferocious —> Very fierce 
 Luminous —> Very light 
 Animated —> Very lively 
 Very lovely –> Adorable
 Cruel —> Very mean 
 Slovenly —> Very messy 
 Kind —> Very nice 
 Frequently —> Very often 
 Ancient —> Very old 
 Transparent —> Very open 
 Ashen —> Very pale 
 Flawless —> Very perfect 
 Compelling —> Very powerful 
 Beautiful —> Very pretty 
 Pouring —> Very rainy 
 Petrified —> Very scared 
 Chilling —> Very scary 
 Grave —> Very serious 
 Keen —> Very sharp 
 Gleaming —> Very shiny 
 Timid —> Very shy 
 Basic —> Very simple 
 Skeletal —> Very skinny 
 Sleek —> Very smooth 
 Downy —> Very soft 
 Apologetic —> Very sorry 
 Exceptional —> Very special 
 Certain —> Very sure 
 Thoughtful —> Very sweet 
 Gifted —> Very talented 
 Delicious —> Very tasty 
 Parched —> Very thirsty 
 Constricting —> Very tight 
 Minuscule —> Very tiny 
 Exhausted —> Very tired 
 Expansive —> Very wide 
 Eager —> Very willing 
 Blustery —> Very windy 
 Sage —> Very wise 
 Distressed —> Very worried
```

I'm concerned to know if all those words are exactly equal to "very + adjective". For instance I wonder if "very + lazy" exactly equals to "indolent", or similarly if they're "synonyms" for all those words. And if they aren't exactly equal what is the slighlty difference for those which aren't?

---

### Improving my question thanks to the relevant comments

Many thanks to @FumbleFingers, @Bee, @Jonathanjo

#### What would be the best interpretations of those adjectives since each sequence of words is never equal to another different one? In what are they different from their "very+adjective"?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no rhyme or reason (logical process) as to how these adjective synonyms are created. You just have to memorize them! I find it easiest to learn a few words each week and try to use them in my conversations and in my writing. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Those alternatives are not equal in meaning but are good approximates to better be used instead.